# Looking for a good iPhone photo viewer

Tags: itunes, applications, photos

I'm looking for a photo viewer that would sync with multiple (sub)folders on my computer HD (some of which are not in my MyPhoto folder), and would have a feature to do a slideshow on the iPhone.

Answer (score 3):

Have you considered [Dropbox](http://www.dropbox.com/)?

It allows for any folder structure you like, and has a decent photo viewing and slideshow capability. And it's free up to a certain size, although depending on the size of your library, you might need to pay.

It's great at a [Ton of other things](https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/11859/what-are-some-great-os-x-dropbox-uses), too.